# VB6 Interface with USB

Tags: .net, interface, vb6, usb, communication

I have been looking for a way to do this all around the internet and have not come back with much, so this is what i'm looking to do:

I have USB game controller. I want to control my application using the buttons on this controller, example if i hit the triangle button my application does something. I have done programs before using COM control but this device does not mount itself as a serial device, only a USB, so anyone have any advice on how I can read data through a HID-class USB device? Perhaps using Direct input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HID API directly but it's a PITA. The best option is to use DirectX.
See the DirectX4VB libraries and website (which we use)
http://directx4vb.vbgamer.com/DirectX4VB/Tutorials/DirectX7/DI_Joystick.asp

**Note that I've only used it from VB6, not .NET.**

Comment: Is there a way to do this using direct input? I am using Visual Basic 2010, are there any examples?

Comment: Yes, DirectInput is part of DirectX that I recomended. I have no idea about using it in .NET though as I've not used it and that wasn't the title of the question.